# How to stress memory on windows 2008 64 bit

Tags: testing

I want to stress memory on windows 2008 64 bit .

i saw code which on msdn magzine . but its not running on windows 2008 64 bit.

Know any good tool for stressing memory ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "stress memory"?  Do you mean you have an application that you want to test in low memory conditions?  Do you mean you want to saturate memory bandwidth on the machine?  Do you mean you want to read/write as fast as possible?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing a native/unmanaged/C++ application you can use [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948.aspx) and it's Low Resource Simulation setting which will use fault injection to simulate errors in memory allocations (among many other things). It's also really useful for finding a ton of other subtle problems that often lead to application crashes.

You can also use consume.exe, which is part of the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) to easily use a lot of memory, disk space, cpu time, the page file, or kernel pool and see how your application handles the lack of available resources. (Does it crash? How is the performance affected? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First declare an `ArrayList`.

Second, create a `for` loop within a `for` loop within a `for` loop ( repeat this 10000 times, or more) and add the count to the list.

The memory will stress out eventually.

There you go! A simple tool to stress out the memory.

**Seriously, why would you want to stress it out? Does it serve any purpose?**

Comment: Perhaps to check how much his application can handle in a single request. Stresstesting is very common when building Large (with a capital L ;)) applications.

Comment: I thought in that case it would be better to stress test the app, instead of memory?

Answer (score 0):

How about installing VirtualBox with several various flavours of Linux Distro's, one a web server, the other a database server, and a few other types of systems, and let each other virtual boxes interact by requesting web pages over virtual ethernet, and run IE web browser from the host, MySQL workbench on the host also, interacting with the database/web servers. Set the limit of RAM for each Virtual machine say 2Gb each with virtual hard disk of 10Gb..now, boot all VM's together at the same time, that would really put a strain on the machine, and it would also put a load on the network stack as well. You could easily put together simple shell scripts for each virtualbox running linux to loop around or read from the disk at intervals...

What do you think?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.