# Test/run a C# application with restricted CPU/RAM in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have my C# application fully developed and targeted to run in CPU and RAM restricted devices.

Is there any way to run/test this application on my development computer by providing parameters of how much CPU, RAM etc. to use?

Comment: You could use a virtual machine. Oracle Virtualbox works great, and is free.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have enough to install a os n test. Target system is windows embedded os. so only put a question.

Comment: Please follow the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285701/how-do-i-limit-ram-to-test-low-memory-situations In that thread they explained how to limit RAM for testing application.

Comment: Especially in the case of Windows Embedded, it is essential that you test on the target system.  You'll never reproduce the *exact* same runtime environment, given the many ways to configure it.

Comment: Did you check [App Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480483.aspx) you should be able to restrict memory and CPU usage when testing your application.

Answer (score 1):

a method would be to get data from resource monitor & then set an upper limit according to it
so when the ram/cpu utilization reaches there the process goes to wait state (regardless of what that makes the utilization higher)
.